# Python Plotly, Main plot title on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

How do I set the main plot title (*python; plotly API*) for separate subplots to display on the y-axis, instead of above the plot. See example image below for what I need:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a hack around in the mean time.

If you add `<b>` and `<br>` to your text, it sort of get's the job done (see example below). Problem is, it's still a single string, so you can't change the size of `Main Title` to be bigger then `ytext`.

`fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='<b> Main Title </b> <br><br> ytext')`

Happy to hear better solutions, but this should work for now.

Also see http://help.plot.ly/adding-HTML-and-links-to-charts/ for plotly's  available html markup.